# Error genérico en GDI+ al imprimir en crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Vengo con un problema que ya me viene afectando varios días y consiste que al momento de mandar la impresión en crystal report de los reportes del personal me arroja una pantalla de error o advertencia no sabría como tomarlo pero el problema es que si envió a imprimir 126 hojas solo imprime 44 y el 45 no imprime dato alguno solo las líneas, adjunto las capturas de pantalla del error y del estado de la impresora que tal como indique solo registra 44 impresiones de un total de 126.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código de mi método Load

```
private void FormReporteIndividual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
            myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
            myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
            myConnectionInfo.Password = "TECNOLOGIA";
            myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            ParameterField pfi = new ParameterField();
            ParameterField pff = new ParameterField();
            ParameterFields pfields = new ParameterFields();
            ParameterDiscreteValue pdvi = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            ParameterDiscreteValue pdvf = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            pfi.Name = "FECHAI";
            pdvi.Value = fechin.ToShortDateString();
            //pfi.CurrentValues.Clear();
            pfi.CurrentValues.Add(pdvi);
            pfields.Add(pfi);

            pff.Name = "FECHAF";
            pdvf.Value = fechfin.ToShortDateString();
            //pff.CurrentValues.Clear();
            pff.CurrentValues.Add(pdvf);
            pfields.Add(pff);

            crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfields;
            SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
            
            rd.Load("Z:/SisRol-Net/Reportes/ReporteRol.rpt");
            
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
        }catch(ExternalException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
            foreach (TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
            {
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda , si hay algo que tenga que mejorar o corregir me indican porque esto ya es un código previamente realizado por otra persona.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso el problema era la forma en la que pasaba los datos

Lo estaba pasando de esta forma

//Esperaba los datos en estas Variables

```
public partial class Visor_imprecion : Form
    {
        public string fecha;
        public double id_ruta;
        public string Nombre_Reporte;
    }
```

//Le pasaba los datos a las variable de esta forma

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Visor_imprecion visor = new Visor_imprecion();
            DateTime date = dp_fecha.Value;              
            visor.fecha = date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            visor.id_ruta =Convert.ToDouble(txt_id_ruta.Text);
            visor.Nombre_Reporte = "Reporte atraso";
            visor.ShowDialog();
        }
```

La solución es pasar los datos de la siguiente manera

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DateTime date = dp_fecha.Value;
           string fecha = date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
           double id_ruta = Convert.ToDouble(txt_id_ruta.Text);
           string Nombre_Reporte = "Reporte atraso";

            Visor_imprecion visor = new Visor_imprecion(fecha, id_ruta,Nombre_Reporte);            
            visor.ShowDialog();
        }
```

// Y Recibir los datos de esta manera

```
public partial class Visor_imprecion : Form
    {
        string fecha;
        double id_ruta;
        string Nombre_Reporte;

public imprimirRecibos(DateTime fecha, double id_ruta, string Nombre_Reporte)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RecibirFecha = recibirfecha;
            RecibirRuta = recibirruta;
            RecibirUno = recibiruno;
            RecibirDos = recibirdos;

            this.fecha=fecha;
            this.id_ruta=id_ruta
            this.Nombre_Reporte=Nombre_Reporte;
        }
    }
```

Lugo asignas los valores al Crystal Report